# Are there probability distributions completely characterized by their nth statistical moments for n>2?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, characteristic-functions

The normal/Gaussian distribution is fully characterized by its first and second statistical moments, $\mu$ and $\sigma$, so we can write the distribution only as a function of these two parameters; $F(\mu,\sigma)$ since the $n^{\text{th}}$ statistical moments vanish

My question is an attempt to generalize this notion and I haven't found much answering this (maybe I'm not phrasing it in the proper terminology). Is there any probability distribution that is fully characterized by  its $n^{\text{th}}$ statistical moments?

(i.e. its $(n+1)^{\text{st}}$ statistical moment vanishes and its strictly a function $F(s_1,s_2,...,s_n)$ where $s_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ statistical moment)

Comment: The 4th statistical moment (which, scaled, is called https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) doesn't vanish for a normal distribution -- "excess kurtosis" is kurtosis shifted so that you get 0 for a normal distribution.

Comment: Seconding the comment by @AlexK; a distribution can be fully determined by its first two statistical moments even if the third/fourth/etc. don't vanish, the moments further up just have to be a function of the first two. I have an answer for you if you're willing to relax that assumption that the statistical moments have to eventually vanish!

Comment: @aghostinthefigures that is of interest to me anyways, so in the case that the higher order moments are not zero but instead functions of the first two, what are such distributions?

Comment: Any family with a single parameter -- eg $\chi^2_k$ whose variance varies monotonically with $k$ will have this property. The higher order moments will be functions of $k$ and if you can get $k$ from the second moment, then you can get the higher moments. I suspect you're looking for something different?

Comment: The generalized gamma distribution seems to fit the bill for what you're looking for; it's fully determined by three parameters and has linearly independent moments that are a function of all three of these parameters, so it can be fully characterized by its first three statistical moments but cannot be characterized only by its first two.